# How can I make separate components to loading in order?

Tags: reactjs

For example, I write this in the sandbox for demonstration only, I don't quite remember the structure of my old project, but I remember that I tried something like this, this is written in 1 component, but I think it's not very good practice, because later on, I remember that I split my components into many more for easier management, but at that point, I can't make it load in order, so whenever the `Home` components are called, it just fetches everything instead of in order, which makes my page load very long due to it try to fetch everything from every component that exists in the `Home` component.

```
import {React, useState, useEffect} from "react"
import axios from "axios"


function Home() {
  
  const [loadingSlider, setLoadingSlider] = useState(true)
  const [loadingCategory, setLoadingCategory] = useState(true)
  const [loadingStuff, setLoadingStuff] = useState(true)

  const [sliderData, setSliderData] = useState()
  const [categoryData, setCategoryData] = useState()
  const [stuffData, setStuffData] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {

    const fetchSlider = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get("sliderUrl")
      setSliderData(response.data)
      setLoadingSlider(false)
    }
    
    const fetchCategory = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get("categoryUrl")
      setCategoryData(response.data)
      setLoadingCategory(false)
    }

    const fetchStuff = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get("stuffUrl")
      setStuffData(response.data)
      setLoadingStuff(false)
    }

    fetchSlider()
    fetchCategory()
    fetchStuff()

  } , [])


  return (
    <>
    {
      loadingSlider ? "Loading slider" : {sliderData}
    }
    {
      loadingCategory ? "Loading category" : {categoryData}
    }
    {
      loadingStuff ? "Loading stuff" : {stuffData}
    }
    </>
  )

}
```

So with this practice, if I split 3 `sliderData`, `categoryData`, `stuffData` into 3 different components, and I just want to call it in `Home` component for easier management, how can I let it load in order?

Each component will `fetch` inside of it separately.

For example:

```
function Home() {

  return (
    <>
      <SliderComponent/>
      <CategoryComponent/>
      <StuffComponent/>
      
   {/* <More components might be added in the future/> */}
    </>
  )

}
```

What do I need to do so it can load in order, and not load all of the components at the same time? I want it done fetching the `slider` first, then it'll proceed to fetch the `category`, and then so on.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
   fetchSlider();
 } , [])

 const fetchSlider = async () => {
   const response = await axios.get("sliderUrl")
   if(response.status === 200){
     // Call another method you want to load
     setSliderData(response.data)
     setLoadingSlider(false)
     fetchCategory(); // Once Slide data is set call category method
   }
 }

 const fetchCategory = async () => {
   const response = await axios.get("categoryUrl")
   if(response.status === 200){
     // Call another method you want to load
     setCategoryData(response.data)
     setLoadingCategory(false)
     fetchStuff(); // Once Category data is set call stuff method
   } 
 }

 const fetchStuff = async () => {
   const response = await axios.get("stuffUrl")
   setStuffData(response.data)
   setLoadingStuff(false)
 }
```

In Short Once you fetch data from method with status 200 then only call another method. And Its your option also even if one method might failed whether you cant to call next method or you want to show error. Hope It might help with your problem.

Comment: Thanks, @Sujit Libi, but at the last example, what if later on, I decided to split it into more components, like in this example, it'll be 3 different components. Then, I just call those 3 components in 1 big component called `<Home/>`, each of those 3 components will contain the fetching method, is there a way I can still do this?